# OpenEdge SQL Field Width on system tables

Tags: openedge

I need to alter the SQL Field Width for columns on the system tables `_aud-audit-data` and `_aud-audit-data-value`.

Is this possible from within the Data Dictionary interface?
Or is there an alternative non-4GL way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to 11.6 using dbtool is the standard way to adjust SQL width.  It is fast, safe and effective:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P24496

You can also use the data dictionary or SQL code to update the SQL width field in the meta schema directly but that is not recommended.

Starting from OpenEdge version 11.6 a new database startup parameter was introduced:

-SQLWidthUpdate ON

that can automatically fix the SQL width of character datatypes (not for numerical datatypes).

More information about this new feature can be found here:

https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_rdbms/f/18/t/19534

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tom - a long overdue parameter in my eyes...  Do you know if I should be able to amend SQL Field width for system tables?

Comment: I don't know offhand.  On the one hand I don't see why not.  On the other hand I'm having a hard time imaging why you would want to.  And on the third hand I generally hesitate to modify the system tables.

Comment: I want to increase the event-Detail width in the audit-data table so that it can cater for nvarchar(max) size values upfront before the application I'm auditing (very quickly) blows the field limit after enabling auditing.

Comment: Ah.  Ok, that makes sense.  Not that anyone does this but, in theory, you're *supposed* to export the audit data to a reporting db rather than report directly from those tables ;)  You probably need to use the audit admin login credentials to make any changes to the audit tables -- if you've already tried that without success then I would open a case with tech support.

Comment: OK, thanks Tom.  Yeah, I'm actually pulling the audits straight out into SQL Server; where they're processed.  So I read them out via ODBC (hence the need to increase the field width) and then extract them using the OE commands.  I'll give the SQL92 another blast.  Do you know if there is a way to use the data dictionary to set sys table field widths?

Comment: I don't have an audit enabled db handy but you can view meta-schema tables by entering their name in the "Schema" --> "Adjust Field Width" table picker.  You do not appear to be permitted to change anything though.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of information about this in the [Knowledgebase](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/).

You can do it by SQL:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P128368

There's a utility called "dbtool" that perhaps you can use. 
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P24496

Note: you might have to prefix the tables with `PUB` ie:

```
ALTER TABLE PUB.<table name> 
     ALTER COLUMN <column name> 
     SET PRO_SQL_WIDTH  <value>;
```

(Code taken from the link above, not tested).

Comment: Yeah, I should have said that I've read the knowledgeable and have been unsuccessful in updating the sql field width on system tables.  And DBTool only works when a column has overflowed already - I want to pre-empt not react...

Comment: Perhaps Toms answer can help?